# Trouble validating <ul> dropdown menu

Tags: html, validation

I am having trouble validating my html, my menus are triggering the following error:

"document type does not allow element "li" here; missing one of "ul", "ol" start-tag"

[link](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2%2Fsuperuntitled.com%2Fglobal%2Fservices) to validator

[link](http://superuntitled.com/global/services) to site

My code is as follows, the menus are drop-down menus

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href='services' class='inactive'>Services</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='services'>Services</a></li>
            <li><a href='brokerage' >Brokerage Group</a></li>
            <li><a href='development-group'>Development Group</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li ><a href='contact'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Am I missing something? Is the ul after the link tag invalidating my code?

Comment: It seems ok. what document type you are using, btw?

Comment: What are you using to validate?

Comment: XHTML 1.0 Transitional // see page here: http://superuntitled.com/global/services

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsuperuntitled.com%2Fglobal%2Fservices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first `<li>` inside the second `<ul>` is missing a closing tag ... looks like you've copied and pasted the code, so the error appears a few times.

```
<ul>
    <li class='headlink'><a href='home' class='inactive'>Home</a></li>
    <li class='headlink'><a href='about' class='inactive'>About</a>
        <ul class='About'>
            <li class='headlink'><a href='about'>About</a> <!-- MISSING TAG HERE -->
            <li><a href='management-team' class='inactive'>Management Team</a></li>
            <li><a href='partners' class='inactive'>Partners</a></li>
            <li><a href='global-one-standard' class='inactive'>Global One Standard</a></li>
            <li><a href='business-investment-opportunities' class='inactive'>Business & Investment Opportunities</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='headlink'><a href='services' class='active'>Services</a>
        <ul class='Services'>
            <li class='headlink'><a href='services'>Services</a> <!-- MISSING TAG HERE -->
            <li><a href='brokerage' class='inactive'>Brokerage Group</a></li>
            <li><a href='development-group' class='inactive'>Development Group</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='headlink'><a href='projects' class='inactive'>Projects</a>
        <ul class='Projects'>
            <li class='headlink'><a href='projects'>Projects</a> <!-- MISSING TAG HERE -->
            <li><a href='hilton-garden-inn' class='inactive'>Hilton Garden Inn</a></li>
            <li><a href='federal-plaza' class='inactive'>Federal Plaza</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='headlink'><a href='contact' class='inactive'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your code very carefully at the locations the validator complains, for example the first error

> Line 41, Column 203: document type does not allow element "li" here; missing one of "ul", "ol", "menu", "dir" start-tag

Is because your code looks like this

```
//...
<ul class='About'>
    <li class='headlink'>
        <a href='about'>About</a>
     //                            <- you have to put </li> here
    <li>
        <a href='management-team' class='inactive'>Management Team</a>
   </li>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your document type is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Are you sure you want to use just that. If not try to use below document type:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Strict document type is checked really strictly; and you should be able to comply with those strict standards.

I am not sure whether this is exactly the cause of issue, but you may want to try it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I have changed it to transitional without any change in the number of errors.

Comment: BS. There's no difference in parsing between Transitional and Strict.

Comment: @ms2ger if that is really so, i probably did not know that. thanks for sharing.